# Using LINQ to create new List<Bar> from List<Foo> where Foo has a variable Bar?

Tags: linq

I have a `List<Foo>`. The type `Foo` has a public variable of type `Bar`. I would like create a new `List<Bar>` from my `List<Foo>` using LINQ.

Is this possible?

Comment: You would use `foos.Select(foo => foo.Bar).ToList()`.

Comment: I would strongly advise reading a LINQ tutorial. This is one of the simplest things you can do with LINQ, which suggests you haven't read such a tutorial yet - and you'll get a lot more out of LINQ by learning about it in a structured way, IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method

```
var bars= foos.Select(f=>f.Bar).ToList();
```